# Customize the width of \widetilde on letters H, K, M, N, W, and X

Tags: fonts, math-mode, bold, tilde

For example either

```
$\widetilde{\bm{H}}$
```

or

```
$\widetilde{\boldsymbol{H}}$
```

would result rather huge tilde over the letter H, K, M, N, W, and X, please see the following alphabet:

[image: The \widetilde \bm alphabet]

I can understand the command adaptively adjust the width for specific letters, but how could I customize this width?

Comment: I suggest removing the references to `\bold...` (in title and in tags) since this happens with non-bold symbols as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This code defines three macros:

1. `\mathcenterto{#1}{#2}` that typesets `#2` to be centered to the size of `#1`;
2. `\widetildeto{#1}{#2}` that put the wide tilde over `#2` but it thinks it is of size `#1`. If you wish to have all wide tildes in the whole document to be the same, you can put `\def\widetilde{\widetildeto{X}}` or any other letter instead of `X`;
3. `\widehatto{#1}{#2}` for `\widehat`.

**Remark: it needs `mathtools` package besides `amsmath`!**

**Warning: the parameters cannot contain active macros, becuase `#1` gets expanded twice and `#2` get expanded 3 times!** You can still use most math macors like `\vec`, `\bm`, `\frac`, ... Prohibited are macros like `\newcommand`, `\addtocounter`, ...

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}

\makeatletter
\def\mathcenterto#1#2{\mathclap{\phantom{#1}\mathclap{#2}}\phantom{#1}}
\let\old@widetilde\widetilde
\def\widetildeto#1#2{\mathcenterto{#2}{\old@widetilde{\mathcenterto{#1}{#2\,}}}}
\let\old@widehat\widehat
\def\widehatto#1#2{\mathcenterto{#2}{\old@widehat{\mathcenterto{#1}{#2\,}}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\[
\widetildeto{I}{W} \widetilde{I}
\]

\[
\widetilde{W} \widetildeto{W}{I}
\]

\def\widetilde{\widetildeto{X}}

\[
\widetilde{W} \widetilde{I}
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, works perfectly. I am a little confused about the remark about `\newcommand` though, is this the reason why you used `\def` instead of `\newcommand`?

Comment: the `mathtools` package loads the `amsmath` package, so you only need to use `\usepackage{mathtools}` :)

Comment: @cmhughes I know, but I tend to load them both. It doesn't hurt and when you use commands from both, it seems to me somehow "cleaner" ... Just a matter of taste

Comment: @Jon No, I use `\def` because I grew up using TeX primitives instead of the LaTeX ones. It has nothing to do with the Remark. The Remark just says: **Don't put anything like `\newcommand` (or `\def`) or such into the patameters of `\widetildeto` and other 2 defined commands.**

Comment: @tohecz Thanks a lot, I got it! Please pardon my reading comprehension. :'(

Comment: No worries :) You're welcome